# If P(a,b|c) is known, how do I find P(a|c) and P(b|c)

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, posterior

I have the posterior distribution P(a,b|c). I would like to find the marginal posteriors P(a|c) and P(b|c). I am not sure if a,b are conditionally independent given c.

I know how to calculate the marginal probability when there is no conditioning. I am confused as to how to go about it when there is conditioning.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do the same thing. $P(A = a_i \mid C = c_i) = \sum_j P(A = a_i, B = b_j\mid C = c_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

By Bayes' theorem, integrate/sum over $b$ to get $P(a \mid c)$ and over $a$ to get $P(b \mid c)$.

Edit: After the above was written, the question was altered to include the bit about marginals when $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily conditionally independent.  The answer is: it doesn't matter, because Bayes' theorem includes it explicitly -- $P(a,b \mid c) \propto P(a \mid b,c)\,P(b \mid c)$, and $P(a \mid c) \propto \int db~P(a \mid b,c)\,P(b \mid c)$ ($\sum_b$ if $b$ is discrete).  Similarly for $P(b \mid c)$.